# PI historical database SDK resources

Tags: resources, historical-db, osisoft, pi-db

I'm looking for any **third-party resources** for programming the OSIsoft PI historical database SDK.  Websites, books, etc.  I already have what OSIsoft puts out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ed said, you should check out http://vCampus.osisoft.com. The OSIsoft vCampus is a community-oriented program similar to Microsoft's MSDN, which provides everything people need to develop applications on the PI System, or integrate PI with other systems.

Every member gets access to:

- a personal PI System for development purposes
- a good number of resources, training and collaboration tools (online library, interactive webinars, discussion forums, blogs, etc.)
- a community of OSIsoft customers, partners and employees (including a dedicated team for vCampus)

Every year, the technical community meets at the OSIsoft vCampus Live! event, OSIsoft's annual in-depth technology event. Contact vCampus@osisoft.com or read the [online FAQ](http://vCampus.osisoft.com/content/FAQ.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I've looked at VCampus, but right now the cost is a little high ($1500) considering we already have the extra system for development.  The rep says they may change the requirements at sometime, so that may be an option.

Comment: There are plenty of free resources on https://pisquare.osisoft.com/.  vCampus does not exist anymore for a while.

Comment: @codea sadly, those resources are very difficult to access and their login system is fundamentally broken (e.g: you can make an account but it has access to nothing) as well as their support not responding to my email/phone call requests :/

Comment: @dtc - as long as you are working for a customer or a company who bought proper PI Sytem Licenses, you can get entitled to support resources and access to phone support. OSIsoft typically has an excellent support.  I would ask around to find out who owns the PI and manages the website so he/she can grant you access.  see https://my.osisoft.com/